# How to wake unmounted external drive within a script?

Tags: command-line, mount, suspend, usb-drive

I have a hard drive in an external enclosure connected to a 14.04 server installation by a USB 2 cable. Periodically a Bash scripted process checks that the correct drive is connected using `lsblk`, collects a series of files and copies them to the drive. 
The drive has normally been connected and powered on for a couple of days before this process takes place.

Very occasionally the drive does not appear to be connected, it appears it has entered some sort of sleep mode from which it is very slow to respond. `lsblk` does not return any of the drive's details and my script responds as if no drive is connected.

I've observed this outside of the script too, sometimes I'll check available drives with `fdisk -l` with two varieties of outcome:

1. The command will take much longer than normal before returning details of the external drive. In this situation executing the command again immediately afterwards will return all of the results at the usual speed.
2. The command runs slowly and the external drive will not be listed in the output at all. If I run the command again the drive appears in the output as
   normal. It just seems as if it didn't respond quickly enough the
   first time.

**Is there a command that I can reliably use in a Bash script to make sure that the external drive is 'awake' and ready to respond?**

I supppose I could use `fdisk -l` and redirect to `/dev/null` but I suspect there's a more appropriate command.

If it's of any use It's a Seagate Desktop HDD ST1000DM003 in a Evo Labs E-U3F  SATA enclosure.